# Cocoa core data app cycles rising memory

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, core-data, memory-management

I'm working on a cocoa app that receives and stores large amount data into core data ( > 500K objects with many reverse relationships). The app has to constantly run in cycles. The problem i encounter is after each cycle the allocated memory is growing by 20-40 megabytes (as indicated by xcode; of course,  same tendency showed by activity monitor).

What i have so far:

- wrapped methods that insert objects into context in autorelease pools;
- reset context, undoManager nil, stalenessInterval 0;
- recreate persistent store coordinator on cycle completion (remove-add the store);
- many hours of profiling, but could not find leak causes

Thought i'll appreciate advices if this list of actions can be improved, my main question is *how should i deal with system memory, which my app will eventually eat up*. Because it's possible i wont be able to optimize my code any more. I must not allow the app to crash due to not enough memory; so the way i deal with it now is i relaunch the app if its memory allocation reaches some hardcoded value (lets say, 1 GB).

I don't like this solution, so hopefully someone can advice me on appropriate way to handle this. Or on ways experienced people handle such situations. Thanks

**UPDATE**

Adding snapshots from instruments and xcode's memory debug gauge when first cycle has finished.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Too less info to really help you. `NSManagedObjectContect` is really in-memory optimised class. Try to perform more saves to your context.Perform saves into bg context with merging to main context. Perform saves more often, it will reduce men usage. If you can't get enough performance with CoreDate, use bare SQLite instead.

Comment: @PetroKorienev objects are inserted into background context; so main context isn't realy used. Bg context is saved frequent enough. Still, the question remains about proper approach to deal with rising memory. I imagine other apps that deal with large amount of data would have similar issues, if ran for long time, and i wonder how developers deal with that

Comment: Really not enough information for a good answer. Try using Instruments, but use the allocations instrument instead of checking for leaks. If memory use rises over time, you'll see what kind of objects are causing that and where they were created.

Comment: @TomHarrington not enough may be. What else you think i should add to get a good answer?

Comment: I don't know what "not enough may be" means in this context. You could post some code that actually shows what you are doing, or at least describe the steps in more detail. And again, you could use Instruments to see what objects are being allocated and what lines of code are allocating them.

Comment: Thanks @TomHarrington, i actually dont know myself what i meant by "not enough memory". Shame to say, but i dont know well enough how OSX's memory management works. Hence, i'm not sure how the system with 4 GB of RAM would menage its memory, if my app allocates that amount or more.About instruments, please see update above. Since i asked this question, i learned that coredata may be totally innocent here, which draws this question irrelevant. I now think i should be asking about system memory management and using instruments properly. So i guess i'l need to delete the question as misleading